# One-Liners Script to (1) Delete a line and the following one, (2) Change a value in the file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

In Linux I have a file with the following structure:

---

[a/b/c]
value = 1

[a/b/d]
value = 0

[a/b/e]
value = 0

---

The keys '[x/y/z]' are unique.
Before and after the equals sign I have \t tabulation (please post the solution even with no \t).
(e.g. value\t\t=\t0)

How can I do the following operations?
(1) Delete a line '[x/y/z]' and the following one 'value = 0', given the key
(2) Change a value of a key in the file:
FROM
[a/b/c]
value = 0
TO
[a/b/c]
value = 1

Comment: This site is for programming questions. It is not "gimme the codez". Since you're not asking any questions, and simply saying, "I need...", you're obviously expecting us to do your job for you. Nope. Not gonna happen.

Comment: @MarcB, Ok, I didn't used the best language. A "How can I do" is much better than an "I need". I just wanted to avoid spending 8 hours learning sed/awk/... when someone that knows bash scripting well can write a one-liner for this this in 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's delete operation in a nice, easy to read awk one-liner:

```
awk -v delkey="[a/b/d]" '{ if ($1 == delkey) { i=3 }; if ( i>0 ) { i-- } else { print }}' file.txt
```

Using that example, see if you can figure out the value change operation.  Awk is very rewarding to learn - well worth the effort.